# Format string without use of static methods

Tags: string, jenkins, groovy, static

I use jenkins and I cannot use `String.format` or `sprintf` due to `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods sprintf java.lang.Object`

I have settings file with creds:

```
    <username>%s</username>
    <password>%s</password>
```

I would like to format it anyway `sprintf(MAVEN_SETTINGS, USERNAME, PASSWORD)`. How can I bypass it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in whitelisting `String.format` and `DefaultGroovyMethods.sprintf` methods. Jenkins workflow plugin is very restrictive by default. Ask your Jenkins administrator for accepting one of these two methods and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about non-static `Formatter.format`

```
new java.util.Formatter().format("n=%s, p=%s","name", "pass").toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with using `sprintf(str, args...)`, but when I tried using `String.format(str, args...)` it worked. Maybe the policy changed over time? I am using Jenkins ver. 2.190.2 and there are no approved exceptions in the script-approval settings page.